# Formula Field to get previous month and year from a given date

Tags: formula, formula-field, date

Suppose i have createddate as 05-05-2016 then formula field 1 should be 042016 and formula field 2 should be 032016.

Two Exceptional cases are:

1. if i have createddate 01-01-2016 (January) then formula field 1
   should be 122015 and formula field 2 should be 112015
2. if i have
   createddate 02-02-2016 (February) then formula field 1 should be
   012016 and formula field 2 should be 122015

Is it possible to get such formula field

Comment: For formula field 1 i am trying like below :

IF((MONTH(Invoice_Date__c ))>=3 ,TEXT(MONTH(Invoice_Date__c )-1) + TEXT(YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)) ,
 IF((MONTH(Invoice_Date__c ))=2,TEXT(MONTH(Invoice_Date__c )-1) + TEXT(YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)),
  IF((MONTH(Invoice_Date__c ))=1,'12' + TEXT(YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)-1),null
  )
 )
)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following formula:

```
IF(MONTH(Invoice_Date) > 1, 
  (MONTH(Invoice_Date__c) - 1) + '' + YEAR(Invoice_Date__c), 
  '12' + (YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)-1))
```

The logic behind. Suppose we have a `01.01.2016`:

- IF the month of the given date is in the range of 2 - 12:

  - output: (month -1 ) & year ---> `for the 01.05.2016 -> 42016`
- IF the month is 1:

  - output: (month => 12) & year => (2016 - 1) ---> `for the 01.01.2016 -> 122015`

Answer (score 0):

For field 1 you can use this formula:

```
TEXT(IF(MONTH(StartDate__c) = 1, 12, MONTH(StartDate__c)-1))&""&TEXT(IF(MONTH(StartDate__c) = 1 ,(YEAR(StartDate__c)-1), YEAR(StartDate__c)))
```

For field 2, you can use formula from field 1:

```
TEXT(IF(MONTH(formulafield1) = 1, 12, MONTH(formulafield1)-1))&""&TEXT(IF(MONTH(formulafield1) = 1 ,(YEAR(formulafield1)-1), YEAR(formulafield1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Formula Field 1 :

```
IF((MONTH(Invoice_Date__c ))>=3 ,TEXT(MONTH(Invoice_Date__c )-1) + TEXT(YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)) ,
IF((MONTH(Invoice_Date__c ))=2,TEXT(MONTH(Invoice_Date__c )-1) + TEXT(YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)),
IF((MONTH(Invoice_Date__c ))=1,'12' + TEXT(YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)-1),null
)
)
)
```

Formula Field 2:

```
IF((MONTH(Invoice_Date__c ))>=3 ,TEXT(MONTH(Invoice_Date__c )-2) + TEXT(YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)) ,
IF((MONTH(Invoice_Date__c ))=2,'12' + TEXT(YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)-1),
IF((MONTH(Invoice_Date__c ))=1,'11' + TEXT(YEAR(Invoice_Date__c)-1),null
)
)
)
```